# »Wie lange« vs. »Wie lang«

Tags: difference, adjective, adverb, interrogative

Worin unterscheiden sich die Ausdrücke *wie lange* und *wie lang*?

> *Wie lange* lernst du Deutsch?
>
> *Wie lang* ist die Arbeitzeit pro Tag?

Comment: Reminds me of this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFDgSKbapzY (0:11)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Lange* ist das Adjektiv zum Adverb lang: *über einen großen Zeitraum*.

- Die lange Arbeitszeit (jedoch als Adverb in: *wie lang ist die Arbeitszeit?*)

> Etwas dauert / scheint / währt lange
>
> Etwas ist lang

Die Verwendung von *lang* als Adjektiv ist umgangssprachlich, aber durchaus gebräuchlich. In der indirekten Rede würde man in diesem Fall die *Auslassung* des *e* anzeigen: *„Wie lang' dauert es?“*

Umgangssprachlich wird *lang* zudem anstelle von *entlang* benutzt.

---

Zum Adverb-/Adjektiv Begriff:

Ich hatte die beiden in dieser Antwort durcheinandergebracht. Dieses Beispiel [aus der Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb) zeigt den Unterschied:

> 1. Das schnelle Auto fährt. (Adjektiv)
> 2. Das Auto fährt schnell. (Adverb)

Comment: Wieso ist die Verwendung von *lang* als Adverb "nicht korrekt"? Bitte keinen unbegründeten Preskriptivismus. Im Zweifelsfall "nicht korrekt" durch "nicht das höchste [Register](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprachebene)" ersetzen. (Und was ist mit dem Adverb *lang* in "sie gingen auf einem Pfad am Ufer lang"?)

Comment: @RegDwight entlanggehen ist ein teilbares Verb

Comment: @bernd_k: den Satz habe ich [aus dem Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lang_entlang_Adverb). Siehe auch die anderen Beispiele, "wir müssen da lang" und "geht es wirklich da lang". Aber zurück zum eigentlichen Punkt: ["*lan­ge*, auch *lang*, Adverb"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lange). Mit dem wunderbaren Beispielsatz "lang, lang ist's her". Ich kenne *niemanden*, der stattdessen "lange, lange ist's her" sagen würde. Von "nicht korrekt" kann also keine Rede sein.

Comment: Ich bezweifele das in "lang, lang ist's her" lang Adverb ist, weder das 1. noch das zweite.

Comment: Beachte, dass in dem Duden Eintrag steht: „Gebrauch: landschaftlich“. Es muss in der tat „wir müssen da entlang“ heißen. „Lang ist's her“ ist eine poetische Floskel ([wp](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_gefl%C3%BCgelter_Worte/L#Lang.2C_lang_ist.27s_her.)); somit ist da auch die Rede von: „es ist schon lange her“.

Comment: @bernd_k: was ist es dann?

Comment: Ich weiss nicht genau. Aber eine analoge Umstellung von `Er geht schnell.` (Schnell ist Adverb) zu `Schnell er geht.` Ist nicht üblich sondern klingt nach Yoda in Star Wars.

Comment: @bernd_k: In dem Satz "Schnell er geht" ist *schnell* nach wie vor ein Adverb. Ebenso in "Er schnell geht", "Geht er schnell", "Geht schnell er" und "Schnell geht er". In allen Fällen ist *geht* ein Verb, *er* ein Pronomen, und *schnell* ein Adverb.

Comment: Eben, es ist sprachlich aber nicht üblich, deshalb denke ich das lang, lang ist's her einfach ein feststehender Ausdruck ist, da die Ableitung nach dem Schema nicht nur gültige Sätze produziert.

Comment: @bernd_k: welche Ableitung nach welchem Schema? Nochmal ganz langsam zum Mitschreiben. Du sagst, *lang* sei kein Adverb; dann sage ich "doch"; dann sagst Du "eben". Was denn nun? (Des weiteren: feststehende Ausdrücke sind per Definition "gültig". Und nur, weil ein Wort Teil eines feststehenden Ausdrucks ist, verliert es nicht seine Wortklassenzugehörigkeit. Im übrigen ist "lang, lang ist's her" einfach nur ein [Hyperbaton](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaton).)

Comment: @bernd_k: Die richtige Analogie ist: 'Schnell geht er.' Interessanterweise bezieht sich das "schnell" hier aber auf den schnellen Beginn der Tätigkeit und nicht auf die Tätigkeit.
Bei zweiteiligen Verben geht es besser (und das ist wohl auch der Grund, dass es bei 'ist ... her' funktioniert):
'Es ist schnell getan.' und 'Schnell ist es getan.'

Comment: Was `Schnell er geht.` betrifft: Wenn man ein Komma oder ein Ausrufezeichen setzt, so bekommt der Satz eine ganz andere Bedeutung: "Schnell, er geht!" Das impliziert: "Macht schnell", ein Aufruf an andere.

Comment: "Lange ist das Adjektiv zum Adverb lang"  Aber in "Etwas dauert / scheint / währt lange" ist _lange_ doch ein Adverb, nicht ein Adjektiv.

Comment: In der Antwort von Stefano Palazzo sind Adverb und Adjektiv systematisch vertauscht. Das sollte korrigiert werden.

Comment: @RegDwight: Zu Deinem zweiten Kommentar: In Beispielen wie 'Hier lang bitte' ist 'lang' die umgangssprachliche Abkürzung für 'entlang'. Der Spruch 'lang(') lang(') ist's her' ist als Beispiel für das Adverb lang(e) ungünstig gewählt, weil hier Zitiergewohnheiten und rhythmische Aspekte die Verwendung von 'lange' blockieren. Der Ausgangssatz wäre 'es ist lange her'. Da könnte man zB auch sagen 'es ist 20 Jahre her', umgestellt: '20 Jahre ist das her - nicht zu fassen...)'. Hier ersieht man klar, das 'lange' als (temporales) Adverbial fungiert.

Comment: @bernd_k - zur Analogie 'schnell geht er' und 'lang ist's her': Die Sätze sind syntaktisch grundverschieden. 'Gehen' ist ein Aktionsverb, 'sein' eine Kopula ohne echten Bedeutungskern, ein Verknüpfungs-Operator. Das Subjekt im 'gehen'-Satz ist 'er', eine Person, das Subjekt im 'sein'-Satz ein zu 's verkürztes 'es', das ebenfalls keine Bedeutung im eigentlichen Sinne hat, sondern ein Strukturwort und Platzhalter für die sonst unbesetzte Subjekt-Leerstelle ist. Der Status von 'lang(e) her' ist nicht leicht zu bestimmen - irgendwas mit Adverb, aber was genau? Erinnert strukturell an '2 m groß'...

Comment: @sgf: 'Lange' ist nicht nur in 'etwas dauert ... lange' ein Adverb, sondern überhaupt, und 'lang' ist das Adjektiv. Ich verstehe nicht, warum darüber hier diese Verwirrung herrscht. Das mag durch 'lange dauern / währen ...' mit bedingt sein, weil 'dauern' bereits ein 'Andauern' impliziert und 'lange' so quasi redundant erscheint. Aber man kann auch sagen 'das Ganze dauerte nur eine Millisekunde', dann wäre 'Millisekunde' Objekt - oder Zeitergänzung? Alternativ:  es dauerte nur kurz / ging sehr schnell / war ruckzuck vorbei. Da gibt es noch mehr von diesen doch etwas speziellen 'Adverbien'.

Answer (score 1):

Der Unterschied bezieht sich im Wesentlichen auf Länge vs. Zeit. Etwas ist lang bezieht sich auf die Länge eines Objekts, während man lange eher im Zusammenhang mit Zeit verwendet. Wie lange dauert die Fahrt? vs. Wie lang ist das Seil?

Comment: Die Antwort ist ein Teil der Wahrheit. 'Lange' ist in erster Linie Adverb (lange warten müssen) und 'lang' in erster Linie Adjektiv. Die Ableitung eines Adverbs aus einem Adjektiv durch Anhängen von -e ist ein altes Bildungsmuster, das heute nicht mehr produktiv und nur noch in Restbeständen vorhanden (von ferne, jemandem nahegehen, etwas reicht dicke, feste zuschlagen). Ein adverbiales 'lange' bezieht sich meistens auf die Zeit. Es gibt aber auch Fälle wie 'das ist lange noch nicht gut' = 'ist von gut noch sehr weit entfernt'; dieses 'lange nicht' ist oft das Gegenteil von 'schon längst'.