# "alleine doch nicht allein" - contrasting a word with itself?

Tags: meaning, usage

According to [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/allein_Adjektiv) and also answers to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1657/allein-or-alleine-as-adverb), "alleine" is just a colloquial form of "allein". Which makes the line in the title very confusing to me, because while I understand that the intended meaning is (probably) "alone but not lonely", I have never before seen such a phrase to contrast a word with *itself*.

Is it correct to contrast different meanings of the same word like this?

Comment: Note: I'm not really sure what tags to put here, please add more appropriate ones or tell me to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrasting a word with itself is certainly possible if the word conveys multiple different meanings

> Kein Zug mehr im Zug. – Bahn schafft Raucherabteile ab.
>
> Dieser Schlag (physisch) war kein Schlag (metaphorisch).
>
> Es ist immer ein Kreuz (metaphorisch) mit dem Kreuz (Körperteil).

The word *allein* or *alleine* has at least the meanings *einsam* and *einzeln*. People feeling alone in groups of other people isn't a seldom thing to happen.

Comment: "Zug" must be a fun word in this regard. I will wait until tomorrow morning to give other people time to chime in, and then accept an answer.

Comment: "Allein ist man am besten zu zweit!"

Comment: @ Michail  No, that "Zug" is not "a fun word". The first one means 'a drag' [of a cigarette], the second one 'train'. Whereas Janka's metaphorical 'Schlag' is quite enigmatic. What she probably meant to convey was 'Unglück, das jemanden getroffen hat; niederdrückendes, unglückseliges Ereignis'

Comment: @multiplexetliber I meant that with the number of meanings it has there're so many opportunities for such usage. I did not mean that it's translated as 'fun word' in this context. (btw, you put a space between '@' and the username, so I didn't get the notification)

Comment: @Michail - Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea maxima culpa :-)) But never shall this happen again. Hopefully! :-))