# Confused by "lange" as adverb

Tags: adverb

While learning German on Babbel, I came across this sentence:

> Ich muss **lange** beim Orthopäden warten.

This confused me, because I thought that it should be *lang* instead of *lange*.  My theory is: We are trying to describe the verb *warten*, so we need an adverb, and I understand that you can use an adjective without any case endings as an adverb, and since there is an adjective *lang*, we should be able to use it as the adverb here without adding any *e*.

Could someone please explain exactly what part(s) of the above reasoning are wrong?

### What I’ve tried so far

My question is essentially [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/534/wie-lange-und-wie-lang), I think — but I’m struggling to understand [the answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/535/3666) (both the reasoning and the language, which is still a bit above my level).  At first it *seems* to agree with my hypothesis that *lang* is the adverb — it says

> Lange ist das Adjektiv zum Adverb lang

but later appears to contradict this with

> Etwas dauert / scheint / währt lange

Are *lang* and *lange* *both* adverbs?  Or is *lange* somehow not considered to be an adverb in *etwas dauert lange*?

Finally, [dict.cc reports that *lang* is both an adjective and an adverb](http://www.dict.cc/?s=lang), as I would expect/hope … But also, to my surprise, that [*lange* is an adverb](http://www.dict.cc/?s=lange).

Comment: It's not that uncommon to have variant forms with and without -e, so both "lang" and "lange" can be used as an adverb. And in your example, it's indeed an adverb (replace it with "kurz": Ich muss kurz warten). OTOH, when "lang" is used as an adjective, it can also take various endings, and "lange" is one possible form.

Comment: @dirkt: [Please do not write an answer as a comment](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/431/why-should-i-edit-or-answer-rather-than-comment)

Answer (score 15):

*Lang* is an adjective. It is used for both, time and distance. As usual, its corresponding adverb is *lang*, but there is also the related adverb *lange*.

The adverb *lange* is used **only** temporal: “*Das dauert lange*”, “*Ich habe lange geübt*”.

The adverb *lang* is used mainly spatial: “*Ich zieh’ dir die Ohren lang*”, “*Das Kleid sieht lang aus*”, “*Hier geht’s lang!*”. *lange* would be wrong here — though I admit, that verbs for spatial adverbs are rare (*ziehen, strecken, machen, wirken, erscheinen, aussehen*).

But the temporal use of *lang* is possible as well. It is found often in speech, particularly when it is strongly emphasized: “*Er hat laaaang geredet*”. An *-e* behind would spoil the echoism.

Some people consider the temporal use of the adverb *lang* as slang, sloppy, or even wrong. I cannot second that, as I’m not aware of a rule forbidding it, and I can hear and read it every day.

But of course I’d say “*Die Spaghetti müssen lang**e** kochen*” — just to make sure, that I don’t expect them to grow ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the image of the Flying Spaghetti Monster ascending out of my pot. I don’t think I can ever cook spaghetti again …

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is the difference between *Wortart* (*word class*) and *Funktion* (*function*).

Adjectives and adverbs are different **word classes**. *Lang* is an adjective, *lange* is an adverb. In general, adverbs can not be derived generically from adjectives in German (in contrast to the english *-ly* derivative). This is not necessary in German because of the following.

The **function** in your sentence is that of an *adverbial* (regard the difference to *adverb*), which means, that it describes the verb/predicate. Adverbials can be formed by adverbs *and* adjectives. Consequently, you can use the adverbial *lange* as well as the adjective *lang* for your sentence.

> Ich muss lange beim Orthopäden warten.
>   Ich muss lang beim Orthopäden warten.

**PS:** Normally, you can differentiate adverbs and adjectives by the ability to be declinated. Adjectives can be declinated, adverbs not. Unfortunately, *lange* looks exactly like a declinated form of *lang*, so that doesn’t work here and helps your confusion.

Comment: Thanks.  Based on your "Adverbials can be formed by adverbs and adjectives", it seems that the rule I heard (namely, that adverbs *can* be derived generically from (endingless) adjectives in German) was an oversimplified version of the true rule, which is about how to form adverbials, not adverbs.  Could you please confirm for me that in the sentence "Ich muss schnell zum Orthopäden gehen", "schnell" is an adverbial and an adjective, but not an adverb?  Thanks!

Comment: Adverbials can formed by adjectives? That's real news to me, can you provide a link for that? If it was true, one should equally be able to say "Ich muss kurze warten", but one can't.

Comment: @dirkt because kurze is not an adverbial. To ger the adberbial you need. to specify additionally: *'Ich muss kurze Zeit warten'*

Comment: @Vogel612: But then you use the adjective to modify a noun, and the whole construct is the adverbial. This is obviously not what this question is about: In "Ich warte lange", "lange" doesn't modify a noun. So while true in this sense, it has no connection to the question. I understood Toscho to mean "you can use an adjective directly in an adverbial, and that's the reason why the adjective 'lange' is used as an adverbial here".

Comment: That would be wrong. In fact the adverbial here also should contain Zeit IMO.. but it seems that was dropped somewhen

Comment: @j_random_hacker You're right. `schnell` is of the word class *adjective* and has the function of an *adverbial*.

Comment: @dirkt Yes indeed, you can use the adjective `kurz` in order to form your adverbial. But you mustn't decline it, because there is no noun to decline it after. If used as an adverbial, the base form of an adjective is used.

Comment: @Vogel612 I don't know what you mean about "should contain Zeit". Could you please explain that.

Comment: Hmm, you say "an adjective may be used as an adverbial". I say "an adjective usually has a corresponding adverb (with the same spelling)".

Comment: In practice, this makes no difference — except for an adjective, which cannot be used adverbial (which I'm not aware of). So far, so good. What puzzles me: Why has *lang* three entries in the Duden (adjective, adverb, and preposition)?

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you are right, *lange* is an adverb.
An adverb describes the verb, for example:

> He *quickly* runs.

There is no difference to it in German.
If you have to/want to describe the process of a verb, in your example the waiting (*warten*) process, we need for some specific verbs the *-e*.

As you said, *lang* is the adjective, but can’t be the adverb.

(Example: Das ist ein **langes** Kabel — Note, that the *-es* comes from ***Das*** Kabel)

For that reason we need the *-e* (like you wrote it in your example)

Comment: Thanks, but "we need *for some specific verbs* the -e" isn't yet clear to me.  Do you mean that we must use "lange" (and must not use "lang") with some verbs (including "warten"), but for other verbs we can use "lang"?

Comment: Why can't "lang" be used as an adverb? You can also say "ich muss lang warten".

Comment: No actually you can't. It's a German language mistake often done by teenagers or children. 
If you want to say it correctly, it's "*lange*", because **lang** is the adjective

Comment: @user3398698 Yes, actually you can. This is no mistake by teenagers and children. There are regional differences in the preference of `lange` vs. `lang`, but both are equally possible.